# How to ensure that all locale files in rails have all keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, rails-i18n

I want to be sure that all my locales have all keys used in application.

I don't want to get the runtime errors like 'translation missing for key <...>' and want to ensure that my locales are properly set up on a CI stage.

Maybe there is some rubocop module for it?

Comment: I don't think so. The lookup can be very dynamic so just finding all the keys used in a application can't really be done with static analysis. That leaves doing a hash diff between a "master" language and the others and checking for nils and running integration tests in different locales.

Comment: You can add tests to make sure the code using translations doesn't return anything else than what's expected.

Comment: I don't think there's a tool for that. What you can do is always use the `:default` option when you translate something https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#defaults

Comment: At least I'd like to check that all my translations has the same key set

Comment: Check out [i18n-tasks](https://github.com/glebm/i18n-tasks) this is a powerful tool that can report on missing translations, unused keys, enforced ordering, quoting and more, and can be run as part of a CI process.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a test suite that hits every page, you can set:

```rb
 config.action_view.raise_on_missing_translations = true
```

in config/environments/test.rb and the tests should fail b/c the page fails to load (with exceptions raised due to missing translations).

It's not ideal b/c the test suite error doesn't report the missing translation...  it's in the log file. But it seems to be a pretty reliable way to prevent missing translations from getting into production.